Creative solutions for range ventilation in challenging townhome?
We are redoing our kitchen and upgrading to a real range hood from an over-the-range microwave with recirculation.
We’re facing a number of challenges with this, though:

The microwave "vent" used a 4-inch duct, and no real vents have 4-inch ducts (clearly)
Our current run of ductwork is at least 20 feet long with at least one 90-degree jog (it runs up to our roof, which is two floors up)
Adding some kind of device to pull air through the ductwork is a non-starter, as we actually have no idea where the jog(s) happen

We’ve live in a townhome and have petitioned our HOA board to allow us to add a 6-inch duct directly outside our exterior kitchen wall, but I’m not holding my breath that they’ll move through that process in time. (Apparently there are structural and indemnification concerns they need to work out if they even decide it's a worthwhile pursuit.)
For vent models, we are considering the following:

Zephyr AK9528AS
Vent-a-Hood M28PSLD (though it's a bit pricier than I'd like)

Do you have any recommendations on how to proceed?
At this point my contractor has suggested we get a 600cfm max vent with a reducer from 6" to 4" and hope for the best… Kinda seems like our only option.
But if you have ideas… I would be more than grateful.

Are you able to access any part of the duct, possibly with some drywall removal?

Might be time to consider an expensive range with downdraft fume extraction, running a duct through the floor.

@keshlam, if the HOA controls access to roof, they'll be even more concerned about structural changes to floor.

@DrMoishePippik: not necessarily. It depends on what their concerns are. Holes in the roof require ongoing maintenance to prevent rain damage. Floor penetrations require very little, if any, maintenance. And if watching friends fight with HOAs and condo boards has taught me anything, it's that they are irrational, which can sometimes be helpful as well as harmful.

@Huesmann, we just don’t know where the duct actually RUNS, and I don’t have access to the blueprints ‍♀️

@keshlam where would said ductwork through the floor actually empty out? Theoretically?

@DrMoishePippik my board is petty af and VERY conservative in terms of approving and making changes.

Well, if you're on the ground floor it can exit the same way the vent from a basement clothes dryer would. If you have an upstairs unit, forget I said anything.

@keshlam thank you for clarifying! It's ours top to bottom, though we're built on a slab and the dryer's on our second floor  I'm just gonna move
